# What happens when a person dies during the flight? What kind of procedures exist regarding deceased passenger on board?

Tags: medical, passenger, crew, flight-attendant, cabin

I was just reading about a young woman who died on the long haul flight from LA to Melbourne. Heartbreaking. Young life cut short. RIP. But this horrible situation made me wonder about a presence of a deceased passenger on board. the article says that she died mid-flight. So there could be another remaining 8 hours of flying. I wonder if there are any regulations on how to proceed with a deceased person on board. where would they put her body? I am sure they probably covered her but still, where would she remain for the rest of the flight? I dont think they would put her back on her seat, and not sure if it is ok just to put her on the floor by the kitchen/bathroom areas. I am sorry i know it is weird but seriously does anyone know if there are any provisions regarding logistics of that kind of unfortunate situation?

Comment: I feel as if there is a duplicate of this question somewhere but I can’t find it.